# Execute Specflow and retrieve result on a cucumber format

Tags: .net, bdd, specflow

We are trying to use Specflow to run some BDD tests on .Net.

The results will be imported into a tool(in fact a JIRA plugin, named XRAY).

For what I'm aware, it should be possible to generate some kind JSON result file(which XRAY is compatible with), but I didn't found how?

Does somebody has a reference/idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Specflow doesn't support creating reports in JSON format natively, but [pickles](https://github.com/picklesdoc/pickles) supports [a JSON format](http://www.picklesdoc.com/Output/JSON/pickledFeatures.json). If this format is not the format you want then you have a couple of options:

- if the existing format has all the information you need but is structurally not what you want, then you can write something to post process the pickles output to convert it to the json format you want
- if the existing format is missing data then you'll be best extending pickles to produce a new output type. It will probably be very similar to the existing [JSON documentation builder](https://github.com/picklesdoc/pickles/tree/6570b6c2bfc230467a297bc332b69c81d245e0f8/src/Pickles/Pickles/DocumentationBuilders/JSON), so grabbing the code and seeing how that is used and taking it from there would be how I would suggest you start.

Good luck!

Comment: I just took a look to pickles, but it seems there "line number" missing from what it parse, not sure if it is critical for xray